# Stop Looping Text but still run the effect

Tags: javascript, text

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ovnah9aj/)

```
var text  = 'ENTER...';
var chars = text.split('');
var enter = document.getElementById("enter")
var i = 0;
setInterval (function(){
    if (i < chars.length){
        enter.innerHTML += chars[i++];
    }else{
        i = 0;
        enter.innerHTML = "";
    }
}, 200);
```

I'm trying to have this typing "enter" effect and I am wondering how to make it only go once. So it will type out "ENTER..." and then stop.
[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ovnah9aj/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var text  = 'ENTER...';
var enter = document.getElementById("enter")
var i = 0;
(function nextLetter() {
    enter.innerHTML = text.substr(0, ++i);
    if (i < text.length) {
        setTimeout(nextLetter, 200);
    }
})();
```

edit: you either have to use setTimeout (one time "sleep"), or remember return value of setInterval and destroy that timer by clearInterval after you don't need it/want it running.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `interval`, you have to stop the it with `clearInterval`. Stop it **inside** the *interval function*, which is declared as a variable, in the `if-statement`:

```
var text  = 'ENTER...';
var enter = document.getElementById("enter")
var i = 0;

var interval = setInterval(function() {
    enter.innerHTML += text[i];
    i += 1;
    if(i === text.length) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }   
}, 200);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ovnah9aj/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var text  = 'ENTER...';
var chars = text.split('');
var enter = document.getElementById("enter")
var i = 0;
var interval = setInterval (function(){
    if(i == chars.length) {
        clearInterval(interval);  
        return;
    }
  
    if (i < chars.length){
        enter.innerHTML += chars[i++];
    }else{
        i = 0;
        enter.innerHTML = "";
    }
}, 200);
```

```html
<div id="enter"></div>
```